# I can't set validation on WPF datagrid template column that contains datepicker and textblock

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

There is datagrid template column contains datepicker and textblock, the datepicker for editing and the textbox for showing.
I try to apply a style on this column to validate it, but it just be applied on the datepicker not the textblock:

```
<Style x:Key="DateEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type my:DatePicker}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                        Value="Plase check the data in the cell"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="TextBlockEditStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" 
                        Value="Plase check the data in the cell"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="SrvDateCol" Header="Date" Width="100">
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <my:DatePicker  SelectedDate="{Binding srvdate,StringFormat=d, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
                            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged"
                            Style="{StaticResource DateEditStyle}"></my:DatePicker>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
    <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding srvdate,StringFormat=d,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

When I enter error date in the cell, the style works good, but when I leave it the style disappeares, and the cell return back to its original state. So how to apply the style on the TextBlock also??
I hope my question is clear.

Comment: Please read the **[formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)**.